# PHP determining what to insert into parent window textarea from child window using radio buttons in child window

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, window, parent

Hi everyone im new to php and would like to know how if it is possible determine what to insert into parent window textarea from child window using radio buttons in child window. How should I go about doing it? I would much appreciate it if anyone could provide some help on this. Below is the code. Thanks.

Parent Window:

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById('b1').onclick = openChild;
}
function openChild()
{
  this.disabled = false;
  xWinOpen('retrievemath.php');
}
var xChildWindow = null;
function xWinOpen(sUrl)
{
  // Modify 'features' to suit your needs:
  var features = "left=100,top=100,width=400,height=400,location=0,menubar=0," +
    "resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=0,toolbar=0";
  if (xChildWindow && !xChildWindow.closed) {xChildWindow.location.href  = sUrl;}
  else {xChildWindow = window.open(sUrl, "myWinName", features);}
  xChildWindow.focus();
  return false;
}
</script>
<script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <textarea class="ckeditor" cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" ></textarea>
<form>
<input type="button" id ="b1" onClick="myPopup2()" value="POP2!">
</form>
<p onClick="myPopup2()">CLICK ME TOO!</p>
</body>
```

Child Window:

```
<?php
include ('database_connection.php');
  $dbConn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '')
             or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
  // select the database for use
  mysql_select_db('test', $dbConn);
$query_retrieve_expression = "SELECT * FROM math";
 $queryResource = mysql_query($query_retrieve_expression, $dbConn) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<head>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function()
{
  document.getElementById('f1').onsubmit = sendToParent;
}
function sendToParent()
{
  if (window.opener) {
    var cta = document.getElementById('<?php echo $row['mathID']?>');
    var pta = window.opener.document.getElementById('editor1');
    pta.value = cta.value;
    window.opener.focus();
  }
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
        <form action="retrievemath.php" method="post" id="f1">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
    <th>Insert ?</th><th>Expression Name</th><th>Math Expression</th>
</tr>

    <?php
               while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResource))
               {     
    ?>

                    <tr> 
                    <td><input type="radio" name="insert" id="<?php echo $row['mathID']?>" value="<?php echo $row['expressionname']?>" /> </td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['expressionname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['mathexpression']; ?></td> 
                    </tr>

    <?php
               }
    ?>


</table>



    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" value="Insert" />
    </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Can anyone please provide some insight on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value for textarea and passed in url like this

**Latest function**

```
function sendToParent()
{
    var cta='';

    var radio=document.getElementsByName("insert");

    for(var i=0;i<radio.length;i++)
    {
        cta+=radio[i].value;
    }

    var pta = var pta = window.opener.document.getElementById("editor1");
    pta.value = cta;
    self.close();
}
```

You can get value of textarea in child window like this

```
echo $_GET['data'];
```

**Child window code**

```
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>

 function sendToParent()
{
    var cta='';

    var radio=document.getElementsByName("insert");

    for(var i=0;i<radio.length;i++)
    {
        cta+=radio[i].value;
    }

    var pta =var pta = window.opener.document.getElementById("editor1");
    pta.value = cta;
    self.close();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="retrievemath.php" method="post" id="f1">
<table class="hovertable">
<tr>
    <th>Insert ?</th><th>Expression Name</th><th>Math Expression</th>
</tr>
<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff66';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';">

</tr>

    <?php
               while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryResource))
               {     
    ?>

                    <tr> 
                    <td><input type="radio" name="insert" id="<?php echo $row['mathID']?>" value="<?php echo $row['expressionname']?>" /> </td> 
                    <td><?php echo $row['expressionname']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['mathexpression']; ?></td> 
                    </tr>

    <?php
               }
    ?>


</table>



    <div class="submit">
      <input type="button" value="Insert" onclick="sendToParent();" />
    </div>
        </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But what Im trying to achieve is that I want the value of the radio button selected in the child window to be passed into the parent window and echoed in the text area of the parent window.

Comment: @user1610834 You have compulsory called sendToParent function in child window.

Comment: @user1610834 you have to remove window.opener.focus(); and write self.close();

Comment: I apologize, Im rather new to javascript. I tried replacing window.opener.focus(); with self.close(); but that did not work.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, alas it is still not inserting the radiobutton value of the child window into the text area of the parent window. Could this be because the html editor CKEditor?

Comment: Not sure about it.Can you tell me your child window display properly checkbox and other values.

Comment: Yes data from the database is shown properly on the child window in a html table with a radio button for each row record for insertion into the parent window.

Comment: You can firstly try your requirement using static code in child window.If you have success then after apply your dynamic logic

Comment: Could there be any problem with the document.getelementbyid?

Comment: If your db mathID does not assign in radio button id then problem is occur.You can see using inspect element or firebug in browser.

Comment: madthID is actually assigned to the radio button id for each record. I tried echoing a selected radio button and its value within the child window itself

Comment: For some reason the value of the selected radio button in the child window is not getting passed back to the parent window's text area.

Comment: You can alert(cta.value); in javascript function and check it

Comment: I tested with static data using the radio button in the child window and it is getting inserted into the parent window. I am beginning to believe the problem lies with fetching the id of the radiobutton when doing var cta = document.getElementById('<?php echo $row['mathID']?>');

Comment: @user1610834 I have found your problem and modify my code plz find on my answer. Title is latest function (copy only sendToParent function of javascript from answer)

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion, but it is still not inserting into the textarea of the parent window. Could it be there may be some problem in the parent window as well?

Comment: You have copy javascript function sendtoparent from answer?

Comment: Yeah I simply placed that function there. Also one thing to note is that the child window does not close after i click the insert button.

Comment: That means there is a error in your code.It is possible to check your code online on your website or other tool

Comment: Ah okay, but are there no other visible problems with my code in the child window?

Comment: Yes this is work for me? I have does not used any database I have used your code and modify and test it.

Comment: And it works on your side minus the database? Like putting selected radio button value from child window into text area of parent window?

Comment: Ya as per my code it's get all the radio button value and insert in textarea

Comment: I have give all the possible solutions for solved your problem.As per my answer you have to able for solve this problem.I will done it using database.

Comment: So you will do it using a database and try?

Comment: Hey i have try using database and regenerate your problem.I have solved it.Plz update sendToParent() javascript function and check it.Problem is that parent window control does not found in child window using form so i have changed it.

Comment: It works now. Thank you! If this doesn't trouble you somemore, I was wondering, could i echo that passed value from child window to parent window in the ckeditor text area? One slight problem though, when there is more than 1 row in the database, and i select one radiobutton, it inserts all the rows from the database. Again thanks for your help!